# Как "сказать" компилятору, чтобы файлы искались также и в подкаталогах?

Tags: c++, makefile

Например, я указываю искать в `-I./mysources`, но там есть ещё куча подкаталогов. Как прописать поиск и в них, чтобы не писать каждый по отдельности?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Recursion.html думаю это вам поможет

Comment: Следует прописывать каждый по отдельности.

Comment: @ВадимАлександру рекурсия в make тут никак не поможет

Answer (score 1):

Решение, конечно, «на коленке», но у меня работает
(*POSIX Make*):

```make
.POSIX:

SUBDIRS = $$(find . -type d ! -name . | sed -e 's/^/-I/g' | paste -d ' ' -s)

build:
	$(CC) $(SUBDIRS) src.c
```

Макро `SUBDIRS` расширяется в команду, которая
находит все дочерние директории в рабочей директории
кроме `.`, подставляет перед всеми флаг
`-I`, и соединяет
в одну строчку. В вашем случае, наверное,
исключать саму директорию `./mysources/`
не понадобится.

Если у вас *GNU Make*, можно вычислить значение один
раз вместо вычисления при каждой замене с помощью:

```make
SUBDIRS := $(shell find . -type d ! -name . | sed -e 's/^/-I/g' | paste -d ' ' -s)
```